# Trouble with Sending HTTP 1.1 GET request

Tags: http-headers, arduino, wifi, pubnub

I am trying to use ***PubNub*** to *publish* a message to a channel but I always get "Connection Failed!".

I know the structure of a *publish URL* is the following:

```
http://pubsub.pubnub.com/publish/<PUB-KEY>/<SUB-KEY>/0/<CHANNEL>/0/%22<MESSAGE>%22
```

I have tested the URL on Google Chrome and it works just fine.

The following is a C flavored code is running on an [Arduino UNO](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardUno) + [Adafruit HUZZAH CC3000 WIFI Breakout](http://www.adafruit.com/product/1469). This is not an Arduino hardware question per se, because I believe there is nothing wrong with my circuit. My issue is with the structure of the HTTP GET request created using [Adafruit CC3000 Library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CC3000_Library).

I am having to go with sending a GET rather than using [PubNub Arduino Library](https://github.com/pubnub/arduino) because it doesn't seem to support CC3000 WIFI module. They have a JSON WIFI and Ethernet examples but both do not communicate with the CC3000 WIFI module.

```
  char PUBKEY[] = "XXXXXXX";
  char SUBKEY[] = "XXXXXXX";

  Adafruit_CC3000_Client client = cc3000.connectTCP(ip, 80);

  if (client.connected())
  {
    client.print("GET /publish/");
    client.print(PUBKEY);
    client.print("/");
    client.print(SUBKEY);
    client.print("/0/");
    client.print("MyPubChannel");  // Channel Name
    client.print("/0/%22");
    client.print("Hello World from Arduino!"); // Msg to publish
    client.print("%22");
    client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
    client.print("Host: ");
    client.println("pubsub.pubnub.com"); 
    client.println();
  } 
  else 
  {
    Serial.println(F("Connection failed"));    
  }
```

I have read [this](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html) page and understood that a correct **GET** request would be of the form:

```
GET /pub/WWW/TheProject.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.w3.org
```

I am pretty sure there is something wrong with my GET request. Can anyone look at this and provide ANY hints as to what could be going wrong?

Comment: Your GET request is fine, except for one small detail.  Your text message is being passed via URL, so you have to url-encode reserved characters, including spaces, eg: `client.print("Hello%20World%20from%20Arduino!");` but that is not your problem since your code is failing on `connectTCP()`. Did you resolve `pubsub.pubnub.com` to the correct IP address beforehand?

Comment: Have you tried calling `Adafruit_CC3000_Client::connect(const char *host, uint16_t port)` directly instead of using `Adafruit_CC3000::connectTCP(uint32_t destIP, uint16_t destPort)`?

Comment: Let us know if you still need assistance with this.

Comment: @CraigConover: Do you guys have a library for PubNub to work specifically with Adafruit HUZZAH CC3000 WIFI providing Publish and Subscribe? I have provided an update to my question, please take a look at it. Thank you.

Comment: I suspect that it is not PubNub that is the *slow* part of this or we wouldn't be very popular in the embedded device realm. I will have one of our embedded experts review this post. Cheers, Craig

Comment: @CraigConover: I never said it was PubNub, actually I was mostly referring to the hardware and my code. Thanks.

Comment: Understood, no worries, no offense taken. Stay tuned for response from our experts on this. I can see my comment seemed a bit defensive though. Sorry about that. Cheers

Comment: PubNub does support Publish subscribe with the ESP8266 - you can take a look here - https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-07-14-basic-iot-publishsubscribe-messaging-for-esp8266/. We do not have a specific library for the CC3000.

Comment: @Bhavana: What about a subscriber method for PubNub working on the Arduino Uno + CC3000? Can you provide something?

Comment: The subscribe is listed in the blog @Bhavana referenced: 
`bool IFA pubnub_subscribe(const char *channel, Pubnub_subscribeCB subCB);`

Comment: @CraigConover: Correct but it is listed for ESP8266. I am looking for a subscribe method that works with *Adafruit HUZZAH CC3000 WIFI*

Comment: Oh ok - @Bhavana stated, we do not have anything for CC3000. You can use REST API if you must.

Comment: I have been trying to send data from arduino to my own local web app but my HTTP request is not processed, is there some link which can have basic example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am finally able to connect to PubNub using the code below.

```
#include <Adafruit_CC3000.h>
#include <ccspi.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "utility/debug.h"

#define ADAFRUIT_CC3000_IRQ   3  // MUST be an interrupt pin!
#define ADAFRUIT_CC3000_VBAT  5
#define ADAFRUIT_CC3000_CS    10
#define WLAN_SSID             "XXXWifi"           
#define WLAN_PASS             "XXX"
#define WLAN_SECURITY         WLAN_SEC_WPA2
#define IDLE_TIMEOUT_MS       3      

uint32_t ip;

// PubNub Setup
#define WEBSITE  "pubsub.pubnub.com"
#define WEBPAGE  "/publish/"
char PUBKEY[] = "pub-XXXX";
char SUBKEY[] = "sub-XXXX";

Adafruit_CC3000 cc3000 = Adafruit_CC3000(ADAFRUIT_CC3000_CS,     ADAFRUIT_CC3000_IRQ, ADAFRUIT_CC3000_VBAT, SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER); // you can change this clock speed
Adafruit_CC3000_Client www;

void setup(void)
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  /* Initialize the module */
  Serial.print(F("\n Initializing WIFI Adapter..."));
  if (!cc3000.begin())
  {
    Serial.println(F("Couldn't begin()! Check your wiring?"));
    while(1);
  }
  Serial.print(F("Ready!\n"));
  Serial.print(F("Connecting to [")); Serial.print(WLAN_SSID);
  Serial.print(F("]..."));
  if (!cc3000.connectToAP(WLAN_SSID, WLAN_PASS, WLAN_SECURITY)) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed!"));
    while(1);
  }

  Serial.print(F("Connected!\n"));

  //Wait for DHCP to complete 
  Serial.print(F("Waiting for DHCP..."));
  while (!cc3000.checkDHCP())
  {
    delay(100); // ToDo: Insert a DHCP timeout!
  }  
  Serial.print(F("Done!\n"));
  Serial.print(F("Resolving PubNub..."));

  ip = 0;

  // Try looking up the website's IP address
  while (ip == 0) {
    if (! cc3000.getHostByName(WEBSITE, &ip)) {
      Serial.println(F("Couldn't resolve!"));
    }
    delay(500);
  }
  Serial.print(F("Resolved!\n"));
  www = cc3000.connectTCP(ip, 80);

  for(int i=0;i<=50;i++)
  {
    char buffer[4];
    dtostrf(i, 4, 0, buffer);
    Publish("ch2", buffer);
  }

  /* You need to make sure to clean up after yourself or the CC3000 can freak out */
  /* the next time your try to connect ... */
  Serial.println(F("\n\nDisconnecting"));
  www.close();
  cc3000.disconnect();
}

void loop(void)
{
   delay(1000);
}

void Publish(char* CH, char* MSG)
{
   if (www.connected()) {
    www.fastrprint(F("GET "));
    www.fastrprint(WEBPAGE);
    www.fastrprint(PUBKEY);
    www.fastrprint(F("/"));
    www.fastrprint(SUBKEY);
    www.fastrprint(F("/0/"));
    www.fastrprint(CH);
    www.fastrprint(F("/0/%22"));
    www.fastrprint(MSG);
    www.fastrprint(F("%22"));
    www.fastrprint(F(" HTTP/1.1\r\n"));
    www.fastrprint(F("Host: "));     
    www.fastrprint(WEBSITE); 
    www.fastrprint(F("\r\n"));
    www.fastrprint(F("\r\n"));
    www.println();
  } else {
    Serial.println(F("Connection failed"));    
    return;
  }

  //Read data until either the connection is closed, or the idle timeout is reached.
  unsigned long lastRead = millis();
  while (www.connected() && (millis() - lastRead < IDLE_TIMEOUT_MS)) {
    while (www.available()) {
      char c = www.read();
      //Serial.print(c);
      lastRead = millis();
    }
  }
}

char* clean(char* MSG)
{
  return MSG;
}
```

Comment: this is what you are requesting a third party site, how can I do with my own web app?